# Parse URL Parameters to the Iframe Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have an `iframe` form  and it is loading from external source. It doesn't allow url parameters to be parsed and automatically inputted into the `input` fields, ie. `site.com/?name=John&last=Doe`.

This is how my form looks like

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="js-input text" data-model="invitee" maxlength="155" name="first_name" required="" value="" type="text">
```

also the form looks like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="js-form" novalidate="">
```

Is there a way I can override these settings and parse the url parameters to the input fields? They are being loaded normally as DOM.

Thanks.

Comment: In the context of a normal website: No, of course not. Same Origin Policy.

Comment: You seem a little confused; autocomplete does not directly have anything to do with the values passed in the querystring. Also you can't affect the content of a third party site loaded in to an iframe.

Comment: I'll edit my question, thanks.

Comment: It's still the same problem on your revised question. If the source of the iframe is from an external domain then you cannot amend it. This is a security feature of the browser - the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I had to ask. Put it as an answer and I'll accept, since it has been helpful. :)